# Yii2, how to use another model for display in view file

Tags: php, yii2

I am sorry for my English. So, I have 3 tables with many to many relation.

And this code which display attributes in view file:

```
    <?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'scientist_id',
        'scientist_name',
        'scientist_surname',
        'scientist_patronymic',
        'scientist_birthdate',
        'scientist_email:email',
        'scientist_phone',
        'scientist_photo',
        'scientist_status',
        'scientist_job:ntext',
        'scientist_additional_information:ntext',
        'field_id', //display field but no data
    ],
]) ?>
```

So I need to display in  " field_id's " which corresponding "scientist_id" from SUMMARY_FIELD table. And how can I do this?

[image: scientst table and other]

Relations with tables in Scientist model:

```
    public function getSummaryFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SummaryField::className(), ['scientist_id' => 'scientist_id']);
}
public function getFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Field::className(), ['field_id' => 'field_id'])->viaTable('summary_field', ['scientist_id' => 'scientist_id']);
}
```

Relations in SummaryField model:

```
    public function getField()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Field::className(), ['field_id' => 'field_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getScientist()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Scientist::className(), ['scientist_id' => 'scientist_id']);
}
```

Comment: show generated relation in model if used gii to create CRUD otherwise create relation in model.

Comment: show your related model .. and we can check you have already the correct relations.

Comment: @InsaneSkull updated.. You did it mean?

Comment: simple way to access other fields using relation is `relationName.field_name`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull and how to get array with field_id's from?

Comment: make anonymous function to get value.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I am trying to do this for example
`[attribute'=>'field_id', 'content'=>function($model){return $model->summaryFields[0]->field_id;]` but it doesn't work

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203711/has-many-relation-in-detailview. If you feel confused, i will make a demo for you.

Comment: @InsaneSkull if you can)

Comment: Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @InsaneSkull wait bro, I guess I did this. Thank you a LOT! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create function in Model:

```
function getFieldId($model)
{
   $string = '';
   foreach ($model->summaryFields as $cat) {
      $string .= $cat->field_id . " ";
   }
return $string;
}
```

And access in view Using `$model->functionName()`:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
   'model' => $model,
   'attributes' => [ 
     [
     'attribute'=>'field_id',
     'value' => $model->getFieldId($data),
     ],
   ],
]); ?>
```